# LNCS template looks different

Tags: templates

I found [several papers](http://eswc2015.semdev.org/program/), [such as this](http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-1361/paper1.pdf), generated through the [LNCS template](http://eswc2015.semdev.org/participate/) that look different from [the ones I'm able to generate](http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-1268/paper3.pdf). Does anybody know why? How can I generate the former?

Comment: Are you using this? ftp://ftp.springer.de/pub/tex/latex/llncs/latex2e/llncs2e.zip

Comment: Yes and as you can see even the PDF in that zip is different from the style I'm looking for.

Comment: The difference is in the font used. Simplest way is to use the `\usepackage{mathptmx}` package to load times font.  Other alternatives are the `newtx` packages (i.e., `newtxtext` and `newtxmath`)

Comment: Not sure that's the only difference. Check for example the difference with the "keywords" section width. I will try the fonts.

Comment: You're right the fonts did the trick!

Comment: did you put `\keyword` inside the abstract?

Comment: @Guido Wanna write a short answer about the fonts?

Comment: @Guido An answer would be nice. I would even upvote it ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is in the font used.The simplest way is to use the `\usepackage{mathptmx}` package to load times font. Other alternatives are the newtx packages (i.e., `newtxtext` and `newtxmath`).

However, recently Springer will revert back all LaTeX papers to Computer Modern.